# assign custom unique id's to angular directive instances?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, user-interface, angularjs-directive

I wrote a sliding panel directive and I can't figure out how to have multiple instances of the directive on a page. I am passing in a `panel-id` attribute to the directive and I need to figure out how to use that `id` to trigger the correct panel instance. I have a codepen here:

http://codepen.io/mcastre/pen/Ejzebd

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is have the individual directives register themselves with the `panelService` on link (add a method called `registerPanel(scope)` to the service for example).

Then your controller methods like `toggleWeightPanel()` just need to pass in the id that identifies your panel and it can search through the scopes of all registered panels to find the matching one, and call the appropriate method on it.

Somewhere in your controller scope you should keep a list of panel ids that you can use in your `ng-click` directives *and* pass down into your panel directives.

Does that make sense?

Comment: So how would the ng-click function know which directive instance to open?

Answer (score 0):

You really shouldn't need a service for this.  A simple true/false param in your code and an ng-show="ShowMe".  And in your code set $scope.ShowMe = true;